# Name for a website page with all kind of posts mixed

Tags: internet

Imagine a website with many kinds of posts: announcement posts, offer posts, question posts etc. For each kind of post there could be a page listing them.

How would you call a page that lists all the posts of all kinds?

All I came up with is "cumulative page", but that sounds obscure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically such inflow is called a "feed" as in "data feed" or "info feed".

If you want it to sound a bit flowery then use any of "potpourri", "melange", "mishmash".

If you want to pretend to be geeky then use "m-tuple" to fake the impression of multiple.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a book uses an index, a website uses a [site map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Site_map) to provide links to all its pages in an organized fashion on a single web page.

Comment: What I mean is not a site map. Containing all posts does not mean providing links to all pages.

Comment: @BartoszMarcinkowski um, the home page? a collage? a poorly designed website?

Answer (score 0):

Just as a book uses a **Table of Contents**, so too can a website.

Or, just as a mall presents you with a **Directory** so you can look at what stores are available and where you want to go, so too can a website.

If you're talking about a situation where your site has Page 1 with content "A", page 2 with "B", etc. up through page 25 with "Y" and finally a page 26 that has content "ABCDEF...Y", you might call page 26 a "comprehensive listing."